# Algebra of matrices and solving simultaneous equations

Tags: determinant, quadratics

[image]

My approach

---

So here I formed 3 equations with 3 variables.

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
x^2 + \sqrt{3}xy + y^2 = 25 \\
x^2 + xz + z^2 = 16 \\
y^2 + z^2 = 9
\end{array}\right.$$

Solving these equation seemed impossible so I tried hit and trial and tried inserting integral values for like $z= 3$ then $y=0$ which gave $x=5$ but contradicted the 3rd equation so is there any simpler way ?

---

It would be great help if someone provides a link for mathjax

Comment: Look at [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/6267) and go down to the part about systems of equations

Comment: Did you solve it by solving each variable using general method?

Comment: Might be possible that the equations while solving include this particular equation in between rather than finding each variable . Thanks

Comment: Do tell me if you find it